# Mathematica's external controllers?

Tags: manipulate

While reading the [Manipulate reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html) I've noticed this line:

[image]

What are the available external devices for that?

Some months ago I was thinking on what would be needed to use a MIDI Controller such as The BitStream 3X above Into Mathematica.

[image]

With my limited knowledge, I thought I could make Max/MSP receive the midi messages and write them down on a txt file, and then Mathematica would read it and use it for controlling something useful, I've asked to a friend  - who have a degree on C.S. - how this could be accomplished, he said me I would need to use the system DLL's for that.

The questions are:

- What are these controllers?
- How would it be possible to transform the MIDI signals into Mathematica?

**Bonus?**: I also have a [KORG Kontrol 49](http://www.korg.co.uk/images/products/software_controllers/kontrol49/hero_kontrol49.jpg) in my table. It's a MIDI controller - does not produce sound, only MIDI signals. - It's possible to translate some MIDI messages (such as button presses) into keystroke emulation through [Bome's MIDI Translator](http://www.bome.com/products/miditranslator). This is by no means contradictory, translating keyboard keys into keystroke emulation is easy, the only thing I kinda have no clue on how I could do it is how to make a MIDI hardware slider control a Mathematica Slider. I've posted this last section because it could be useful for someone.

Comment: The `controls` are user input devices, such as joysticks, gamepads, (built-in) accelerometers etc., not, as far as I know, MIDI devices.

Comment: Interesting: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2001/Mar/msg00379.html

Comment: Sometime ago, I tried a [3Dconnexion SpaceNavigator](http://www.3dconnexion.com/products/spacenavigator.html) space mouse which worked fine.

Comment: You can also connect microcontrollers, such as [Arduino](http://williamjturkel.net/2011/12/25/connecting-arduino-to-mathematica-on-mac-os-x-with-serialio/) and [Phidgets](http://williamjturkel.net/2011/12/28/connecting-phidgets-to-mathematica-on-mac-os-x-with-jlink/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MIDI devices are supported as controllers on Mac, but not other platforms. Plug your device in and evaluate `ControllerState[]` to get the name of the device and its buttons/axes.

Comment: Only on Mac? So sad.